# gnuMake, How to have an environment variable override

Tags: gnu-make

Currently I am working with Makefiles that have definitions like

```
MYLIB=/.../mylib-1.2.34
```

The problem is that these are different for different developers, and it is a pain having to re-edit the file after every checkout.

So I tried exporting a specific environment variable, and then doing

```
MYLIBX:=$(MYLIB_ENV)
MYLIBX?=MYLIB
```

Trouble is that if MYLIB_ENV is not defined, it still creates an empty MYLIBX, so the ?= does not work.  Is there a clean way to do this very basic thing?

I am working with a "rich" set of make files developed over many years that do all sorts of things like make and call each other, so changing things deeply is not an option.

SOLUTION

Double shuffle.  MYLIB already defined.

```
MYLIB_ENV?=MYLIB
MYLIB:=MYLIB_ENV
```

Comment: First of all, Why is it different for each and every developer? If you really want to read the environment variables then use `export` for the variables you want to get in your `Makefile`

Comment: @Thushi, it just is different, do not go there.  Yes, of course export, that is not the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: So `export`ing environment variable is working for you now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with

```
MYLIB:=$(MYLIB_ENV)
MYLIB?=/.../mylib-1.2.34
```

is that `MYLIB` is always defined in the first line, so the second never applies.

The typical approach in this situation is just

```
MYLIB?=/.../mylib-1.2.34
```

That way individual developers can specify their own value from the shell, either on the `make` command line

```
make MYLIB=...
```

or in their environment before running `make`

```
export MYLIB=...
make
```

(so they can set it once, *e.g.* in their shell startup scripts, and forget about it).

If you just run

```
make
```

without specifying a value for `MYLIB`, the default `/.../mylib-1.2.34` is used.

Another option is to [determine where the Makefile is stored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18136918), but that doesn't work in all cases (in particular if the path to the Makefile contains spaces).

Comment: Thanks, but does not answer the question.  There must be a default withing the make files.  There are many makefiles in a complex arrangement.  So neither of your approaches is useful (and my question actually contains them.)

Comment: The approach I describe *does* contain a default: if `MYLIB` isn't defined externally, it takes the value `/.../mylib-1.2.34`.

Comment: Yes, of course.  My situation is slightly different, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what it is exactly that you are after. But in case you want that you need to override the settings of the make variable MYLIB to something different from what it is specified in the Makefile WITHOUT having to edit the Makefile for that, then it is very simple: In your `make` invocations, specify `MYLIB` on the commandline with a value of your choice , like as:

```
make -f yourmakefile yourtarget MYLIB="I_need_my_personal_value"
```

Another method :

```
MYLIB := ORIGINAL_VALUE

ifneq '$(MYLIB_ENV)' ''
MYLIB := $(MYLIB_ENV)
endif
```

Comment: Thanks.  First solution is impractical, there are many make files in a complex arrangement.  Second would work -- it is what I was trying to avoid though.